# How is Siegel's lemma applied in number theory?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, transcendental-numbers, diophantine-approximation

In the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%27s_lemma), Siegel's lemma is stated as follows:

> Consider the system  $$ \begin{cases} \sum_{i=1}^Na_{1i}X_i=0\\
> \vdots\\ \sum_{i=1}^Na_{Mi}X_i=0 \end{cases}, $$ where the
> coefficients $a_{11}, a_{12}, \dots, a_{MN}$ are integers between $-B$
> and $B$. The system has a nonzero integer solution $(X_1, X_2, \dots,
>  X_N)$ such that $\max_i \left|X_i\right| \le (NB)^{M/(N-M)}$.

In my understanding, Siegel's lemma is of great importance in Diophantine approximation. However, I haven't been able to find an example of a problem where this formulation of the lemma has been applied to problems in Diophantine approximation. How is this applied in number theory?

Answer (score 4):

There are several works in the general context of approximation of subspaces of Euclidean spaces by lattices, which use Siegel's lemma. To give an example, see the paper [Applications of Siegel's Lemma to a system of linear forms and its minimal points](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.06121). A key result involved is [Schmidt's subspace theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_theorem), which has many applications on Diophantine approximation.

Answer (score 4):

This theorem, as well as algebraic number theoretic extensions, is used to great effect in Ivan Niven’s book: “irrational numbers”, to prove the Gelfond-Schneider theorem (among other things).

I recall it being used in a proof of Baker’s theorem, too.